# AIR HTMLLoader window.open is not working

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

I have a web project developed in Flex which I have to make work standalone using AIR.

I created Air project and loaded the web application using flash.html.HTMLLoader.
The content is loading fine and working.

There are few buttons which open different links using javascript functions window.open.

The links are not opening. The javascript function is getting called using ExternalInterface and I placed alerts in that which is displaying.

The function contains simple window.open

```
window.open("http://www.google.co.in","Google");
```

I tried several solutions mentioned but none of them are working.

```
http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=672
http://soenkerohde.com/2008/09/air-html-with-_blank-links/
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=9243
```

I even tried loading a simple page in HTMLLoader component with window.open method still it is not working. On button click only alert is working but window.open is not opening the link.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<body scroll="no">
<input type="button" value="Click" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.co.in');">
</body>
</html>
```

Could some one help me please

Comment: Are you trying to make it pop up in a new window? Are you expecting it to create a new HTML Component, or have it launch with a native browser?  Also, please try `window.open('http://google.com','_self')` just to see if it's not a security issue--the HTML Component for AIR is a rather sensitive environment.

Answer (score 0):

The AIR Webkit environment is quite restrictive in its support for the `window.open` method.  See Adobe documentation on [Restrictions on calling the JavaScript window.open() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f11.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e91).

The easiest way to deal with this is just let the system's default browser open the links. [Adobe documents this very question](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cba.html), and shows how you can pop open url's from within AIR:

```js
var url = "http://www.adobe.com"; 
var urlReq = new air.URLRequest(url); 
air.navigateToURL(urlReq);
```

Generalizing this:

```js
function openExternalLink(href:String):void {
  var urlReq = new air.URLRequest(href);
  air.navigateToURL(urlReq);
}
```

One option: Assuming you're running jQuery on the page, you could have all the links open externally as so:

```js
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader(); 
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("whatever.html"); 
html.load(urlReq); 
html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
  function completeHandler(event:Event):void { 
    html.window.jQuery('a').click(clickHandler); 
  });

function clickHandler( e:Object ):void { 
  if (e.target && e.target.href) {
    openExternalLink(e.target.href);
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

For more on handling DOM Events in ActionScript, see the [relevant Adobe Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecf.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e84).

None of that is tested, but hopefully it gives a rough outline.

---

Otherwise, if you are trying to do something fancy, like pop up AIR windows with HTMLLoader frames in them, I did find one blog post discussing that: [Opening links in AIR’s HTML loader](http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=672)

Comment: Hi frnds,

Many thanks for your replies. The problem is a bit different as the window.open call is within javascript file. Flash swf is calling Javascript function which opens the link.

The window.open call fails silently for local/remote files.

I tried navigateToURL which is working but that would need several changes across application.

Is there any solution to the specific problem.

Comment: @NitinMukesh - Okay, that makes it a bit more complicated, since it sounds like you don't really have an ability to search the DOM for elements that use `window.open` calls.  I'm going to post a second answer, as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is a radical suggestion that may or may not work, but I think it's worth a try.

**Override the `window.open` method itself**

As before, wait until the `Event.COMPLETE` is fired, then take it from there:

```js
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("whatever.html");
var oldWindowOpen:Object; // save it, just in case

html.load(urlReq);

html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
  function (event:Event):void {
    oldWindowOpen = html.window.open;

    html.window.open = asWindowOpen;
  });

function asWindowOpen(href:String, name:String="_blank", specs:Object=null, replace:Object=null):void { 
  var urlReq = new air.URLRequest(href); 
  air.navigateToURL(urlReq);
}
```

You should probably fill out some of the function to handle the other inputs as specified in the [W3Schools Reference for Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).  You may have to (or want to) change all the parameter types to `Object`, just to be safe, since, unlike ExternalInterface interactions, the JavaScript-ActionScript types are not automatically typecast across the AIR-WebKit exchange.